# How do i show the progress bar while recyclerview is loading and hide it when done?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-progressbar

i have a recyclerview which displays data requested by volley. I'm using the handler().postDelayed to show the progress bar for 4 seconds but it's not consistent with my the recyclerview because sometimes it takes more than 4 seconds to get data from api and display it in the recyclerview and sometimes it takes less tham that.
But i want the progress bar to run as long as the recyclerview isn't visible yet.

**This is my code**

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            stopProgressbar();
        }
    },4000);

    new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            loadData();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call `stopProgressbar()` from `onResponse()` and `onErrorResponse()` method.

**Here is an example:**

```
public void loadData()
{
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Method.GET,
            url, null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, response.toString());

                    // Parse JSON data and add to list
                    ...........
                    ...........................

                    // Hide progressbar
                    stopProgressbar();
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());

                    // Hide progressbar
                    stopProgressbar();                    
                }
            });

            ..................
            ..........................
 }
```

Comment: Glad to know that :) happy coding

Answer (score 1):

**No need of separate handler to handle progressbar.**

You can stop once you get response from the volly. You should call `stopProgressbar();` method from there.

If and only If you facing some main thread issue write it under `runOnUIThread()` method.

Comment: if i use 'runOnUIThread' or 'Handler().post' the progressbar doesnt show. It shows only when i use 'Handler().postDelayed'